# android - autocomplete text view is not updating

Tags: android, autocomplete, progress-bar

I try to update the autocomplete textview data from the web service based text typed in the textbox. It's working fine but i put the progressbar at the time of web service call because it will take some time in this case autocomplete text view is not showing the drop down menu. I guess autocomplete textview is dissmissed at the time of progressbar dissmissed. How should we put the progress bar in this case.

```
Code
```

class GetFundNames extends AsyncTask {

```
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(BasicAutoText.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onPreExecute()");
        progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    // three dots is java for an array of strings
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

        try {
            response = getNames(strKeyword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ;

        return response;
    }

    // then our post

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        if(progress.isShowing())
        {
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        if (ETF_Constants.registerResponsevalue == 200) {
            JSONArray arObjects;
            try {
                arObjects = new JSONArray(response);
                arProducts = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
                arProducts.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < arObjects.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jOb = arObjects.getJSONObject(i);
                    ProductData pd = new ProductData();

                    int fundId = jOb.getInt("fundId");
                    String con = "" + fundId;
                    String fundName = jOb.getString("fundName");
                    String priceAndDate = jOb.getString("priceAndDate");
                    String recentGain = jOb.getString("recentGain");
                    String recentGrowth = jOb.getString("recentGrowth");
                    String tickerName = jOb.getString("tickerName");

                    pd.fundId = con;
                    pd.fundName = fundName;
                    pd.priceAndDate = priceAndDate;
                    pd.recentGain = recentGain;
                    pd.recentGrowth = recentGrowth;
                    pd.tickerName = tickerName;

                    arProducts.add(pd);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // autocomplete
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BasicAutoText.this,
                    R.layout.advancelist);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            AUTO_View.setAdapter(adapter);

            System.out.println("adapter" + adapter);
            for (int i = 0; i < arProducts.size(); i++) {
                adapter.add(arProducts.get(i).fundName);
                System.out.println("Fund Name:"
                        + arProducts.get(i).fundName);
            }
            System.out.println("arProducts count:" + arProducts.size());
            System.out.println("adapter count:" + adapter.getCount());

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } 
    }

}
```